# what's the best way to pad this div?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to convert my website from table layout to div layout,
while with the table layout everything was more intuaitive, I get stuck every minute with this div layout, here's my current problem -

I want the text in my left div to be padded from the left and from the top.
If I pad the left DIV itself, the whole div gets expanded (even though the container div has a 700px width defined for it); If I try to margin the text itself, for some reason it only works for creating the left margin, but it doesn't effect the top margin which stays at 0px.

here's my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">I want some padding here
        <div id="image">image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
border: 1px solid #DCD7D4;
width: 700px;
min-height: 680px;
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#left {
float:left;
width: 500px;
min-height: 680px;
background-color: #F6F1ED;
}
#left #image {
position: absolute;
left: 27px;
bottom: 40px;
background: green;
width: 375px;
height: 48px;
}
#right {
float: left;
width: 194px;
min-height: 680px;
background-color: #F2EEEF;
}
#right #text {
position: absolute;
left: 523px;
top: 154px;
background: yellow;
width: 150px;
height: 70px;
}
#middle {
    float:left;
    background: #0C9;
background-image:url(midbg.png);
    width: 6px;
    min-height: 680px;
 }
```

Comment: Simplest fix sounds like it would be to reduce the width in accordance with the padding you add. Increasing the width when adding padding is normal per the CSS box model as pointed out by phirschybar (except in ie6... Or when you use the border-box box-sizing danield suggests).

Answer (score 4):

You can add padding to your #left div together with `box-sizing: border-box` and the layout should remain in tact

```
#left
{ 
   padding: x px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me :/, the divs are still getting stretched out, maybe because I have 3 divs side by side, a different solution is needed?

Comment: anyone knows why it doesn't work? I'm curios about this type of solution

Comment: @jayjay could you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Danield in fiddle it does work - http://jsfiddle.net/cJtNc/1/ , but it doesn't on dreamweaver CC...

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the CSS box model here: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Padding will affect your overall element's specs.

ALSO, this is a great trick for dealing with funky padding of various elements: 
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

How about either of these solutions.  They work on my browser:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"><span style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px">I want some padding here</span>
        <div id="image">image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

OR

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"><div style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px">I want some padding here</div>
        <div id="image">image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Comment: the additional DIV seem to work, but I'm not sure that adding an additional div is the optimal solution, I'm not sure what are the other aspects to consider here; 
the span does not work for the top padding, only for the left padding for some reason (like I mentioned in my post)

Comment: I've reverse engineered many other people's pages and found that most people use many layers of nested elements, often nested divs.  They are the building blocks of a div based page.

Comment: ok, top padding would work only with adding also - position:absolute;

Comment: Also, I don't think it's such a good idea any more to make fixed positioned pages.  With so many different screen sizes today, fluid pages are really the way to go.  Learning to use divs is the first step, but you need to learn to use them in a fluid way so they spread and float with the available screen width and height.  my 2c for what it's worth.

Comment: by fluid do you mean responsive css? it's important for me to have some text line breaks in certain positions, I'm not sure that its possible to both maintain these breaks and have a responsive design at the same time.. is it?

Comment: @jayjay here is a good page that fairly discusses the different design approaches.  fluid is not for everyone but I made my main production site all fluid so it would operate seamlessly on big screens and tiny screens with just one page served.

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the link..?

Answer (score 1):

if `border-box` is not working then span should work for you, check this  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNFNj/)

**CSS**

```
#left > span {
    padding:100px;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #000;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="left"> 

   <span>I want some padding here</span>
  <!-- rest of html -->
```

`

**EDIT**

Since, your `#left` has child `divs`  inside, you can not apply padding option to it.

`padding` is required on text directly under `#left` id and not a child div,so, `span` is suggested as `<span>` is an inline element and `<div>` is block level element.

Comment: thanks, thats similar to my user name was hijacked solution, not sure if it's the optimal one though; height:100% is not required though

Comment: yeah...saw that late, upvote his answer please.....btw,it is the only option you have bcoz `#left` already contains other `class`es in it....so either provide a different `class` or `span` to you `padding text`....but if `span` solves your problem, i wouldnt suggest to create another class!! :)

Comment: I'm curios to know why not? isn't it better to have less inline design code, so that it's better to include the design in a class on the .css file, to clear up the html?

Comment: @jayjay : added an edit...check if you cn unerstand!

Comment: not yet - why use a long span instead of a short class (that would contain the span definitions in a separate .css)?

Comment: sorry, I get you now, forgot for a sec that span would be required either way, whether with or without a class

Comment: so its clear to you now.....why `<span>` *(which is `inline` element)* should be used???

Comment: yes thanks, still not sure though if i should go with span rather than try the box-sizing thing that currently doesn't work

Comment: i'll suggest you to implement `box-sizing` as it more in use and new standard, but if it doesnt work out for you than use `span` method as a fallback!!! :)